# Vertical text css like below image

Tags: css

[image]

I want to get css for verical text like above image.

but not like this
H
O
U
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@john; you can use css3 `transform` for this 
**css:**

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
```

check this for more http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation

`css3 transform` property is does not supported by `IE` so fot that you cna use `IE rotation filter`

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Zb38/

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you mean when you say "but not like this H O U R", but a possible solution is the following:

```
div {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vndAT/1

Using [`transform:(rotate(<angle>)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-functions) you can rotate any element in the angle you wish. The above prefixes support webkit, gecko and presto layout engines.

For internet explorer a possible solution is `filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=<value>);`

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532972%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment IE is the only browser to support it starting from IE5.5 and up, IE8 adds further values through using the -ms extension. There are 4 values available from IE5.5+ and an additional 4 values for IE8+ through the -ms extension.

```
lr-tb – This is the default value, left to right, top to bottom
rl-tb – This flows the text from right to left, top to bottom
tb-rl – Flows the text vertically from top to bottom, right to left
bt-rl – bottom to top, right to left
tb-lr – This and the followings value are only available in IE8+ using -ms-writing-mode. Text flows top to bottom, left to right
bt-lr – Bottom to top, left to right
lr-bt – Left to right, bottom to top
rl-bt – Right to left, bottom to top
Rotate text in other browsers?
```

we can do this in Webkit based browsers, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 11 and IE9 using the transform property.

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);   
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
```

**LIKE:**

In to the  section put your CSS:

```
<style>
<!--
.verticaltext {
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
}
-->
</style>
```

And into the body:

```
<div class="verticaltext">Test-1</div>
```

The result, if it works in your browser, should be:

[image: http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/images/vertical1.gif]